# express sessions cookie same site typescript error

Tags: typescript, express, session, cookies, samesite

I'm currently getting a typescript error when trying to define my express session config to sameSite: 'none'. I'm currently using @types/express-session: 1.17.3 and have tried unsuccessfully with an older version too.

The documentation indicates that what I'm doing is right, but the Type definitions are somewhat wrong. https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html

In the index.d.ts of express-sessions it indicates that I can use it that way, but I'm getting a  compiler error.

index.d.ts for express-session

```
 class Cookie implements CookieOptions {
        /** Returns the original `maxAge` (time-to-live), in milliseconds, of the session cookie. */
        originalMaxAge: number;

        maxAge?: number;
        signed?: boolean;
        expires?: Date;
        httpOnly?: boolean;
        path?: string;
        domain?: string;
        secure?: boolean | 'auto';
        sameSite?: boolean | 'lax' | 'strict' | 'none';
    }
```

My session config:

```
  const sessionConfig = {
    secret: config.sessionSecret || '',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: false, // if set to true tests won't work
      maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000 * 100000,
      sameSite: 'none',
    },
  };

  if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
    sessionConfig.cookie.secure = true; // serve secure cookies
  }

  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: config.clientUrl,
      methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
      credentials: true,
    }),
  );
  app.use(session(sessionConfig));
```

The Typescript error:

```
src/loaders/middleware.ts:35:19 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ secret: string; resave: boolean; saveUninitialized: boolean; cookie: { secure: boolean; maxAge: number; sameSite: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SessionOptions'.
  The types of 'cookie.sameSite' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "none" | "lax" | "strict" | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a type definition for `sessionConfig` and then give the `cookie` attribute the type `CookieOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like typescript is generalizing the type of `sameSite` in your cookie config. You could try the following in order:

Annotate `sessionConfig` as the expected type of `SessionOptions` right away

```
const sessionConfig: SessionOptions = {
  // ...
}
```

Define the `cookie` options as type `CookieOptions` as imported from `express-session`

```
const cookie: CookieOptions = {
  secure: false,
  maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000 * 100000,
  sameSite: 'none',
};
const sessionConfig: SessionOptions = {
  // ...
  cookie,
};
```

Or simply prevent the type generalization of `'none'` by making it a constant value

```
const sessionConfig: SessionOptions = {
  // ...
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000 * 100000,
    sameSite: 'none' as const,
  },
};
```